# PHP's register_shutdown_function() using an anonymous function

Tags: php, anonymous-function

According to the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php, register_shutdown_function() is implemented as:

```
<?php
function shutdown()
{
    // This is our shutdown function, in 
    // here we can do any last operations
    // before the script is complete.

    echo 'Script executed with success', PHP_EOL;
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
?>
```

Could it be implemented as an anonymous function?  If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous function are simply passed as an argument:

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
    // Code
});
```

Note that this applies to every function, not only to `register_shutdown_function();`

The only differences between using a named function vs an anonymous one, is if you need to call this function outside the context of `register_shutdown_function`, at this point you need to use a named function (altho this is a rare edge case).

Comment: Thanks dynamic.  Easier than I expected!  Any reason not to do so?

Comment: can anyone elaborate on "outside the context of register_shutdown_function" with an example?